# prove or disprove that the integer solutions to equation $x^2-2xy+y^2-x+y+1=x^3-2y^3$ are only ( x=1, y=0) and (x=-2, y=3).

Tags: diophantine-equations

integer solutions to equation $x^2-2xy+y^2-x+y+1=x^3-2y^3$  are  only ( x=1, y=0) and (x=-2, y=3).

This question is related to another question about a system of equations. I showed how these solution can be the solution of system of equation but the condition is that they must be the only solutions.

Comment: $(x,y)=(-5,-4)$

Comment: I think, when $x=-2$, $y \ne 3$. Also $(-1,-1)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

To disprove the given statement, it is sufficiently enough to provide a counter example;

$(x=-1,y=-1)$ is an integer solution to the given equation.

Hence the statement is false.

---

Another way to disprove the statement is that $(-2,3)$ is not a solution.

Hence the statement is false.